# Html range slider with output

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I have been trying to create something similar to this, take note of example 1: **[Bootstrap Slider](http://seiyria.github.io/bootstrap-slider/)**.

As you can see from the following example the `output` has the effect of being fixed onto the slider thumb, and using the **[bootstrap tooltip](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_tooltip.asp)** for styling.

**Alignment:** - 
I have seen other people attempt to create this effect but the `output` never seems to stay perfectly inline with the thumb as you slide it along, here is an example:

[image]

As a designer and front end developer it's important that designs are pixel perfect, so this being perfectly inline is a must.

The Bootstrap example works great but it uses a lot of javascript that I really don't need, I'm wanting to just use the HTML input element with the `type="range"`, and style it according with a little javascript to be functional.

**This is what I have so far:**

```js
var r = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=range]'), 
    prefs = ['webkit-slider-runnable', 'moz-range'], 
    styles = [], 
    l = prefs.length,
    n = r.length;

var getTrackStyleStr = function(el, j) {
  var str = '', 
      min = el.min || 0, 
      perc = (el.max) ? ~~(100*(el.value - min)/(el.max - min)) : el.value, 
      val = perc + '% 100%';

  for(var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
    str += "input[type=range][data-rangeId='" + j + "']::-" + prefs[i] + '-track{background-size:' + val + '} ';
  }
  return str;
};

var setDragStyleStr = function(evt) {
  var trackStyle = getTrackStyleStr(evt.target, this); 
  styles[this].textContent = trackStyle;
};

for(var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  var s = document.createElement('style');
  document.body.appendChild(s);
  styles.push(s);
  r[i].setAttribute('data-rangeId', i);
  r[i].addEventListener('input', setDragStyleStr.bind(i), false);
}

function outputUpdate(value) {
document.querySelector('#slider').value = value;
}
```

```css
html {
  background: #393939;
}

input[type='range'] {
  display: block;
  margin: 2.5em auto;
  border: solid .5em transparent;
  padding: 0;
  width: 15.5em;
  height: 1em;
  border-radius: .25em;
  background: transparent;
  font-size: 1em;
  cursor: pointer;
}
input[type='range'], 
input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-runnable-track, 
input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}
input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  width: 15.5em;
  height: 0.5em;
  border-radius: 0.25em;
  background: #fff;
}
input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  background: linear-gradient(#e44e4f, #e44e4f) no-repeat #fff;
}
input[type='range']::-moz-range-track {
  width: 15.5em;
  height: 0.5em;
  border-radius: 0.25em;
  background: #fff;
}
input[type='range']::-moz-range-track {
  background: linear-gradient(#e44e4f, #e44e4f) no-repeat #fff;
}
input[type='range']::-ms-track {
  border: none;
  width: 15.5em;
  height: 0.5em;
  border-radius: 0.25em;
  background: #fff;
  color: transparent;
}
input[type='range']::-ms-fill-lower {
  border-radius: 0.25em;
  background: #e44e4f;
}
input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  background-size: 0% 100%;
}
input[type='range']::-moz-range-track {
  background-size: 0% 100%;
}
input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  margin-top: -0.125em;
  border: none;
  width: 0.75em;
  height: 0.75em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0.125em #333;
  background: #fff;
}
input[type='range']::-moz-range-thumb {
  border: none;
  width: 0.75em;
  height: 0.75em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0.125em #333;
  background: #fff;
}
input[type='range']::-ms-thumb {
  border: none;
  width: 0.75em;
  height: 0.75em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0.125em #333;
  background: #fff;
}
input[type='range']::-ms-tooltip {
  display: none;
}
input[type='range']:focus {
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0.25em #e44e4f;
}
output {
    color: white;
}
```

```html
    <div>
      <input id="range" type="range" value="0" oninput="outputUpdate(value)">
      <output for=range id=slider>0</output>
    </div>
    <div><input type="range" value="0"></div>
    <div><input type="range" value="0"></div>
```

I have also included an external link of the code **[JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/bajedevune/1/edit)**

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: You said the bootstrap example works well but includes extra js you dont need. Why not start with he bootstrap version and start pairing it down to only what you need?

Comment: There is 1400 lines of javascript, I think it would be easier just expanding onto what I already have.

Comment: Plus I'm pretty sure you have to keep all of the licences, and authors of the original code in the comments section at the top of the document, I'd prefer to not do that.

Comment: I think you can pull specific components from boostrap

Comment: Could you expand more on that?

Comment: Heres a library written from someone outside of bootstrap:
https://github.com/seiyria/bootstrap-slider

Comment: http://seiyria.github.io/bootstrap-slider/

Comment: That's exactly the same link in my question...

Answer (score 3):

What about making it track the mouse's x position over the span of the input element's width and setting its y position according to the input element's location in the document? See the snippet below. If anything, my answer is too smooth (actually smoother than the input itself which is slightly choppy). If you want it to follow the choppiness of the input, just do a little coding to change the px value into a percentage (as the input is) and go from there.

Otherwise, I think this is the answer you are looking for. Just change the styling to your preferences (I did a quick job just to make it actually work)

Oh and have the function run when the document is loaded and resized. That way it starts out in the right position and remains there

```js
var r = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=range]'),
    prefs = ['webkit-slider-runnable', 'moz-range'],
    styles = [],
    l = prefs.length,
    n = r.length;

var getTrackStyleStr = function (el, j) {
    var str = '',
        min = el.min || 0,
        perc = (el.max) ? ~~ (100 * (el.value - min) / (el.max - min)) : el.value,
        val = perc + '% 100%';

    for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        str += "input[type=range][data-rangeId='" + j + "']::-" + prefs[i] + '-track{background-size:' + val + '} ';
    }
    return str;
};

var setDragStyleStr = function (evt) {
    var trackStyle = getTrackStyleStr(evt.target, this);
    styles[this].textContent = trackStyle;
};

for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    var s = document.createElement('style');
    document.body.appendChild(s);
    styles.push(s);
    r[i].setAttribute('data-rangeId', i);
    r[i].addEventListener('input', setDragStyleStr.bind(i), false);
}

var mouseDown = false;
var el = document.querySelector("#slider");
var input = document.querySelector("#this");

function outputUpdate(value) {
    el.value = value;
    el.style.top = input.offsetTop + 30 + "px";
}

(function () {
    document.onmousemove = handleMouseMove;

    function handleMouseMove(event) {
        var dot, eventDoc, doc, body, pageX, pageY;

        event = event || window.event; // IE-ism

        // If pageX/Y aren't available and clientX/Y are,
        // calculate pageX/Y - logic taken from jQuery.
        // (This is to support old IE)
        if (event.pageX === null && event.clientX !== null) {
            eventDoc = (event.target && event.target.ownerDocument) || document;
            doc = eventDoc.documentElement;
            body = eventDoc.body;

            event.pageX = event.clientX + (doc && doc.scrollLeft || body && body.scrollLeft || 0) - (doc && doc.clientLeft || body && body.clientLeft || 0);
            event.pageY = event.clientY + (doc && doc.scrollTop || body && body.scrollTop || 0) - (doc && doc.clientTop || body && body.clientTop || 0);
        }
        if (mouseDown) {
            if (event.pageX < input.offsetLeft + 14) {
                el.style.left = input.offsetLeft + "px";
            } else if (event.pageX > input.offsetLeft + input.clientWidth) {
                el.style.left = input.offsetLeft + input.clientWidth - 14 + "px";
            } else {
                el.style.left = event.pageX - 15 + "px";
            }
            // Use event.pageX / event.pageY here}
        }
    }
})();
```

```css
html {
  background: #393939;
}

input[type='range'] {
  display: block;
  margin: 2.5em auto;
  border: solid .5em transparent;
  padding: 0;
  width: 15.5em;
  height: 1em;
  border-radius: .25em;
  background: transparent;
  font-size: 1em;
  cursor: pointer;
}
input[type='range'], 
input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-runnable-track, 
input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}
input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  width: 15.5em;
  height: 0.5em;
  border-radius: 0.25em;
  background: #fff;
}
input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  background: linear-gradient(#e44e4f, #e44e4f) no-repeat #fff;
}
input[type='range']::-moz-range-track {
  width: 15.5em;
  height: 0.5em;
  border-radius: 0.25em;
  background: #fff;
}
input[type='range']::-moz-range-track {
  background: linear-gradient(#e44e4f, #e44e4f) no-repeat #fff;
}
input[type='range']::-ms-track {
  border: none;
  width: 15.5em;
  height: 0.5em;
  border-radius: 0.25em;
  background: #fff;
  color: transparent;
}
input[type='range']::-ms-fill-lower {
  border-radius: 0.25em;
  background: #e44e4f;
}
input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  background-size: 0% 100%;
}
input[type='range']::-moz-range-track {
  background-size: 0% 100%;
}
input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  margin-top: -0.125em;
  border: none;
  width: 0.75em;
  height: 0.75em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0.125em #333;
  background: #fff;
}
input[type='range']::-moz-range-thumb {
  border: none;
  width: 0.75em;
  height: 0.75em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0.125em #333;
  background: #fff;
}
input[type='range']::-ms-thumb {
  border: none;
  width: 0.75em;
  height: 0.75em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0.125em #333;
  background: #fff;
}
input[type='range']::-ms-tooltip {
  display: none;
}
input[type='range']:focus {
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0.25em #e44e4f;
}
output {
  color: white;
  background-color: red;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  position: absolute;
}
output::before {
  width: 0;
height: 0;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 0 5px 10px 5px;
border-color: transparent transparent #ff0000 transparent;
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  content: " ";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script><div>
    <input id="this" type="range" value="0" onmousedown="mouseDown = true;" onmouseup="mouseDown = false;" oninput="outputUpdate(value)">
    <output for="range" id="slider">0</output>
</div>
<div><input type="range" value="0"></div>
<div><input type="range" value="0"></div>
```

Comment: Yeah it is pretty choppy, when you say change the output unit from `px` to a percentage, could you show a demo? Or a comment in the syntax?

Comment: Perhaps you could include the bootstrap tooltip like I mentioned in my question too?

Comment: Not choppy, but very inconsistent across browsers. It works perfectly in Firefox, but Chrome wigs out and displays the output randomly on the left hand side

Answer (score 0):

Check this link: https://css-tricks.com/value-bubbles-for-range-inputs/

This is the code

```
    <html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src=https://rawgit.com/jeffshaver/styl.js/master/src/styl.min.js></script>
<style>

/*position container at the center*/
.container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
          transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

input[type=range] {
  -webkit-appearance: none; /*remove default style*/
  background: none;
}
/*style for track*/
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  height: 5px;
  background: #ddd;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

input[type=range]::-ms-track {
  height: 5px;
  background: #ddd;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

input[type=range]::-moz-range-track {
  height: 5px;
  background: #ddd;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
/*style for thumb*/

input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  border: none;
  height: 16px;
  width: 16px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #555;
  margin-top: -5px;
  position: relative;
}

input[type=range]::-ms-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  border: none;
  height: 16px;
  width: 16px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #555;
  margin-top: -5px;
  position: relative;
}

input[type=range]::-moz-range-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  border: none;
  height: 16px;
  width: 16px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #555;
  margin-top: -5px;
  position: relative;
}
/*hide the outline behind the border*/
input[type=range]:focus {
  outline: none;
}
/*pseudo-element for the thumb*/
input[type=range]:focus::-webkit-slider-thumb:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: -35px;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
          transform: translateX(-50%);
    border: 10px solid transparent;
    border-bottom-color: #333;
    top: 100%;
    left: 50%;


}
input[type=range]:focus::-ms-thumb:after {
 position: absolute;
  top: -35px;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
          transform: translateX(-50%);
    border: 10px solid transparent;
    border-bottom-color: #333;
    top: 100%;
    left: 50%;


}
input[type=range]:focus::-moz-range-thumb:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: -35px;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
          transform: translateX(-50%);
    border: 10px solid transparent;
    border-bottom-color: #333;
    top: 100%;
    left: 50%;

}

input[type=range]:focus::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  background: #ccc;
}

input[type=range]:focus::-ms-track {
  background: #ccc;
}

input[type=range]:focus::-moz-range-track {
  background: #ccc;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <input id="test" type="range" min="0" max="100" step="1" value="0"/>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('input[type="range"]').on('mouseup', function() {
  this.blur();
}).on('mousedown input', function() {/*on mousedown, the position of the thumb is set to content and this style is injected using styl.js*/
  styl.inject('input[type=range]:focus::-webkit-slider-thumb:after, input[type=range]:focus::-ms-thumb:after, input[type=range]:focus::-moz-range-thumb:after', {
    content: "'" + this.value + "'"
  }).apply();
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for editing in some more information, but you really should add commentary. Explain why this helps. Explain what this code does. Explain **how and why** this addresses the problem. Also, it would be great if you could clean up the code formatting -- the post is hard to read.

Comment: Thanks for the response @Subhashini but in my question I inserted a screenshot, the screen shot I used for  an exmaple was actually from the CSS Tricks site that you just linked me too, it output bubble never stays perfectly inline with the slider thumb unlike the bootstrap one.